# Grails gui:datePicker not displaying

Tags: grails, datepicker

I am trying to display gui:datePicker in grails

```
<div style="margin:0 20px 0 0;display:inline" class="yui-skin-sam">
    <label for="fromDate">From :</label><gui:datePicker id="fromDate" value="${new Date()}"/>
</div>
```

but, it displaying only blank space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put <gui:resources components="datePicker"/> within the head?

Please read the Usage section here for further info:
http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui

EDIT: Installation of grails ui plugin is required
`grails install-plugin grails-ui`
Read: http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui

Comment: yes, i already put resources tag within head...it's not displaying. 
Do i have to add any plugin for this ?

Comment: yes you need to install the grails-ui plugin.. this can be done by doing `install-plugin grails-ui`

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Now, i am facing problem to install this plugin. I am behind proxy, so i have set proxy...still not able to install....Is there any other way to install ?

Comment: yeah you can - i'm not sure of how to do it though. google can really help you out. also, please upvote my answer and/or comment if you have found them useful.